# How do I pass query parameters on in the MVC default route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC2 project where I want the default route to pass on query parameteres to the default action.

Right now I have a route like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "Default", // Route name
     "", // URL pattern
     new { controller = "Search", action = "Index" }
);
```

If I now go to `http://mysite`, that is correctly routed to the Index action on the Search controller, but if enter `http://mysite?theme=yellow`, then the `theme` parameter is not passed to the same action.

How can I make a default route that passes on any given query parameter?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. `http://mysite?theme=yellow` should resolve to the default controller and pass the querystring through, but shouldn't literally change the url in your browser to `http://mysite/Search/Index?theme=yellow`. Are you sure you have no redirect code, RedirectToAction calls etc ?

Comment: Ok I probably worded myself wrong there - it's not redirected, its ROUTED to the Search controller and Index action. I'm changing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

routing has nothing to do with query parameters. They will be accessible from the controller that matches the url pattern.

so, `"{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL pattern` should suffice

and in the controller you can get to query parameters through the Request property:

```
var theme = Request["theme"];
```

or you can be explicit if you want to:

```
var theme = Request.QueryString["theme"];
```

Comment: No they're not. `Request.QueryString = {}` in my debugger when i set breakpoint on line 1 in the Index action after having typed `http://mysite?theme=yellow` in the URL field of the browser.

Comment: Could it be a difference in MVC2 vs MVC3 here? PS: I also tried your URL pattern without success.

Comment: That's weird, I've just tested your code and it works for me. On that breakpoint, what does Request.RawUrl say?

Comment: yes, I can't reproduce your error either. I get the Query string just fine.

Comment: Request.RawUrl was "/", but I just discovered that `http://mysite/?theme=yellow` works! Note the trailing slash. With that URL, Request.RawUrl is "/theme=yellow". That's just weird. Doesn't sound remotely "raw" to me. But I guess that means you're right after all :)

Comment: Update two: if we define this as a bug, this bug is not present when running under IIS. Only under the ASP.NET Development server

Comment: Update three: It's also only present when running under a non-default virtual path on the development server (Project settings > Web > Virtual path"), and not entering a trailing slash there. No wonder you couldn't reproduce it.